# Separate the proxy:port and the username

Tags: php

I have this string `45.142.34.3920:8945:userq:passwd`what I want is I need to separate the proxy address and the port and it's username and pasword. So it should look like `45.142.34.3920:8945` and `userq:passwd`

Comment: Only IPV4 address will ever occur?

Answer (score 1):

Would that help to get you started?

```php
$string = '45.142.34.3920:8945:userq:passwd';

$parts = explode(':', $string);

$host = $parts[0] . ':' . $parts[1];
$user = $parts[2] . ':' . $parts[3];

echo $host . PHP_EOL;
echo $user . PHP_EOL;
```